# "no definition found" for arrow-function parameters using JSDoc @param

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

VS Code seems to ignore JSDoc parameter type definitions for ES6 arrow functions:

```
/** @param {MyClass} myParam */      // VS Code ignores this??
x = (myParam) => {
        myParam.myClassMemberFunc()
    }
```

In the above example, if I hover the pointer over `myParam`, the popup reads:

`(parameter) myParam: any`

when I would expect it to read:

`(parameter) myParam: MyClass`

So of course VS Code cannot find the definition of `myClassMemberFunc` since it doesn't pick up the type definition.

Am I doing it wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: try passing comment after `=`

Comment: https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1286#issuecomment-308899921

Comment: @DanilGudz Thanks, that actually works WITHOUT parens (ie: `x = /** @param {TypeOfP} p */ p => foo(p)` I thought I had tried that, but I probably used @type instead of @param, =/  If you want to leave it as an answer, I'll accept it.